# get alexa ranking using php

Tags: php, web-hosting

```
<?php
$url="http://stackoverflow.com/";
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url='.$url);
$rank=isset($xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY)?$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes()->TEXT:0;
$web=(string)$xml->SD[0]->attributes()->HOST;
echo $web." has Alexa Rank ".$rank;
?>
```

[i getting an error while accessing the file through my website(https://rockynetwork.000webhostapp.com/rank.php
I want to get Alexa rank for my website)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYaSj.png)

ERRORS:

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=http://stackoverflow.com/:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /storage/ssd5/619/12913619/public_html/rank.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): Okay in /storage/ssd5/619/12913619/public_html/rank.php on line 3

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in /storage/ssd5/619/12913619/public_html/rank.php on line 3

Notice: Trying to get property 'SD' of non-object in /storage/ssd5/619/12913619/public_html/rank.php on line 5

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function attributes() on null in /storage/ssd5/619/12913619/public_html/rank.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd5/619/12913619/public_html/rank.php on line 5

Comment: Please add any error messages as text (rather than images) as well as some more description of what you are trying to achieve to your question.

Comment: I don't know about you, but your alexa site just returns a "Okay" for me, which isn't any XML.

Comment: I want the Alexa rank for my plugin, but the requesting data in the third party application it blocking